# how to make one yield in multiple yield function

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following code in my scrapy spider, the parse method has two yields apparently both are happening,how can I make it so if `scrapy.Request...` happens it doesn't also `yield item`

```
for company in self.companies:
    for i in range(1, 3):
        if item[f"Merchant_{i}"] == company:

            yield scrapy.Request(url=item[f"Merchant_{i}_link"],callback=getattr(self, f"parse_{company.lower()}"),meta={'item': item})

yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make additional flag, for example:

```
made_request = False
for company in self.companies:
    for i in range(1, 3):
        if item[f"Merchant_{i}"] == company:
            made_request = True
            yield scrapy.Request(item[f"Merchant_{i}_link"], getattr(self, f"parse_{company.lower()}"), meta={'item': item})

if not made_request:
    yield item
```

So, your item will be yielded only in case there was no request done in cycle.

Comment: Strange. Did you investigate, why? Because this logics is pretty straightforward.

Comment: this was my first thought actually but it didn't work

Comment: @programmerwiz32 didnt work? its simple, it MUST work... did you get any syntax error or what?

Comment: @Umair no error both are yielded (the same as before)

Comment: does it matter if I have CONCURRENT_REQUESTS more than one?

Comment: Can you update your question with this block of code with condition? // CONCURRENT_REQUESTS do not matter here.

Comment: @programmerwiz32 see my new answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work, set `companyFound` at class level, not inside `parse`

```
class MySpider():

    companyFound = False

    def parse(self, response):
        for company in self.companies:
            for i in range(1, 3):
                if item[f"Merchant_{i}"] == company:
                    self.companyFound = True
                    yield scrapy.Request(item[f"Merchant_{i}_link"], getattr(self, f"parse_{company.lower()}"), meta={'item': item})

        if not self.companyFound:
            yield item
```

Comment: In case using it on class level, then maybe use `self.companyFound`? Because right now it is still variable inside `parse` block.

Comment: Ah yes, use self keyword

Comment: this lowered it but still few are duplicated